# Why include a private key in a root certificate?

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, rootkits

In the recent Dell root certificate issue (see https://threatpost.com/dell-computers-ship-with-root-cert-private-key/115455/), the private key was included with the certificate.    This is baffling to me, and I have trouble believing such an "error" could be made in a structured development environment.

Is there any valid reason to include a private key in a root certificate?

Comment: The whole idea that the private key is part of the certificate is maybe to blame here. This (over) simplification is all over the Microsoft API's. So it may be just a mistake where too much was experted during certificate export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the private key of a CA certificate if you want to sign another certificate. This is the case with SSL interception proxies like various Antivirus products provide and also the infamous [Superfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfish) ad-injecting software.

The main problem is if the private key is easily retrievable by an attacker so it can be used (together with the certificate) inside a man in the middle attack. This is typically the case if the same certificate and key is used on multiple installations of the same software, as done by Superfish. SSL intercepting Antivirus products instead create a unique certificate and key for each installation and thus are not affected that much by the problem.

You also need the private key if the certificate should be used for client authentication, i.e. if the computer should identity itself in a secure way within TLS/HTTPS connections. But in this case you usually only have a leaf certificate which can not be used to issue new certificates. Contrary to that the certificates used in the Superfish and eDellRoot certificate are CA certificates, i.e. can be used to issue new certificates and thus can be used for man in the middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this page:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc754329.aspx)

> In some cases, you may want to export a certificate with its private
>   key to store on removable media or to use on a different computer.

In regards to Dell, I'd say they did this by accident.

Answer (score 0):

## Seems to be part of Service Tag readout mechanism

I don't really understand the grand idea behind it, but it seems that Dell Foundation Services runs an HTTP server locally. And when you query that server (via a [JSON-API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)) it will answer with the computer's "Service Tag". (Which is a unique identifier/serial number for Dell hardware.)

And [blog post from hacker group Lizard Squad](http://lizardhq.org/2015/11/25/dell-foundation-services.html) (archived [here](https://archive.is/lhvR5)) continues:

> Dell Foundation Services starts a HTTPd that listens on port 7779. Generally, requests to the API exposed by this HTTPd must be requests signed using a RSA-1024 key and hashed with SHA512.

So that's why you need a pubkey/privkey pair. (I *think*.) But this does not explain at all, why you would need to store that pair as a CA, of all things. Our why you would have to store it in Windows' certificate manager at all.

I'd appreciate further explanations.